# Erroneous calculation using self-reciprocity of cyclotomic polynomials?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Because of self-reciprocity of cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(x)$ we have
$$x^{\phi(n)}\Phi_n\left(\frac 1x\right)=\Phi_n(x)$$
with the Euler totient function $\phi(n)$. Now I concluded/calculated
$$\prod_{d|n}x^{\phi(d)}\Phi_d\left(\frac 1x\right)=\prod_{d|n}x^{\phi(d)}\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d\left(\frac 1x\right)=x^n\left(\left(\frac 1x\right)^n-1\right)=1-x^n$$
and get on the other side
$$\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)=x^n-1$$
Sorry: I dont see what I do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation doesn't hold for $n = 1$, for which $\phi(n) = 1$, $\Phi_1(x) = x - 1$, $\Phi_1(1/x) = 1/x - 1$, and
$$
x^{\phi(1)} \Phi_1(1/x) = 1 - x \ne x - 1 = \Phi_1(x).
$$

So there is a minus sign for $n \ge 1$, for $1|n$.

Comment: Ok. I overlooked the text "A consequence is that the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(x)$  are self-reciprocal for $n > 1$" in the Wikipedia entry "Reciprocal Polymonial". Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann.  That's a tricky one.  I enjoyed your questions.  Happy thanksgiving!